# IE Chopping off left of DIV

Tags: jsp, html, menu, slider

In IE6 the left of the `#right-content` DIV is cut off. I've been playing with it and can't get it to display properly.

http://philzit.com/services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is the -60px margin on the #right-content div.

You can try adding

```
position:realtive
zoom:1
```

As these often solve these kinds of problems for me.

Comment: Is "realtive" a typo or intentional?